# Uploading sketch to Arduino from Mathematica

Tags: undocumented

Since the device drivers for Arduino used by `DeviceExecute` have very poor performance for writing and receiving serial data to/from Arduino compared with the device drivers for a standard serial port I decided to write my own event handler sketch for Arduino.

All works reasonably well: the Arduino listens on the serial port for a number of specified commands + parameters and an appropriate state machine executes some code and returns the result to mathematica via serial. I started writing some functions in Mathematica to automatically generate the C code for the Arduino like with `DeviceExecute` and would like to upload the code via Mathematica as well.

Mathematica clearly has this ability build-in already (see `DeviceConfigure`) but the internals are not documented. With the spelunking package I searched through the `ArduinoLink` namespace and found functions that seem to do all the magic behind the scene but I am lost at the wall of code that are `ArduinoConfigureDriver`, `arduinoUpload`, `arduinoIndividualUpload` and `arduinoCompile`. Has anybody played with those or another method of uploading to an Arduino from within Mathematica?

Comment: Before `ArduinoLink` made its way into *Mathematica* as a built in feature it was distributed via Github. The code is [still available](https://github.com/keshavsaharia/ArduinoLink), and would perhaps be easier to work with than spelunking. Also the spelunking package is obsolete now that ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions`` is built in.

Comment: @C.E. As far as I can tell, the source code is available for the built-in ArduinoLink, with comments and everything: `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "ArduinoLink"}]`